# How to see the concurrency group key used for a job?

Tags: github-actions

I am currently debugging a GitHub Actions workflow that gets cancelled unexpectedly. I suspect it has to do with a bad concurrency group key.

How can I see what concurrency group key was used for a workflow run? Here is an example workflow: https://github.com/aptos-labs/aptos-core/actions/runs/7031129639. I've looked everywhere on the UI but couldn't find anything.

I couldn't see this information from the `gh` CLI either:

```bash
gh run view 7033036961
```

Is the only option to add a step to a job that prints out the concurrency group key?

Comment: I don't think you can, it's not listed as exposed [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts). But you _could_ just copy-paste the expression and e.g. `echo '${{ github.workflow }}-${{ (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.ref) || github.sha }}'` in a job.

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up doing, it's a workable solution.